# In laravel app, using breeze, how to localize the login/register error messages?

Tags: laravel, breeze

I have the laravel 10 app, use breeze. I am looking for a way to localize the login and register validation error messages. In general, the localization works, I have the locale configured. (it seems to me, this has nothing to do with breeze, but I mention that too, just in case)

I have the lang/{myLocaleCode}/validation.php file translated. But I can not find the messages like "Please fill out this field" amongst the keyValue pairs. Neither in lang/en/validation.php version. Neither I do not find the instructions in documentation. I also tried to grep the strings from the whole application folder but nothing was found, which is quite weird too.

Comment: Which lang directory are you using, did you publish it with `php artisan lang:publish`?

Comment: I did this
php artisan lang:add sk
php artisan lang:update

Comment: I mean validation pop up disappearing messages. The same messages also show up when the field is hovered.

Answer (score 0):

You can find some error messages in `lang/{locale}/auth.php`.

Example

```
'failed' => 'These credentials do not match our records.',
'throttle' => 'Too many login attempts. Please try again in :seconds seconds.',
```

This means that you can access with this keys `auth.failed` and `auth.throttle`

Comment: There are 3 messages in my auth.php with keys failed, password and throttle. These are fine, localized version shows up. Except these messages, there are pop up fields which have these texts: Please enter a part folloving '@'. xyz@ is ioncomplete.. or Please fill out this field.

Answer (score 0):

These messages are browser built-in messages.